# Javascript combine string that has the same name,how?Strophe

Tags: javascript, concatenation, strophe

I am using strophe mam with ejabberd server and i am trying to combine the messages it returns and saves it in a sessionstorage or string.

The situation is as such, a function returns me multiple strings that has the same name,for example:

```
var message =HI;
var message= how are you;
var message = i am fine;
var message = how about you?;
```

I am not exactly sure how the strophe plugin runs, but i dont call a loop, it just echos all those out. I console.log it and basically what i have above is given in the console log. 
How would i combine the above into something like

```
var combinedmessages = HI,how are you,i am fine,how about you?
```

Or just combine them?
 var combinedmessages = HIhow are youi am finehow about you?

I tried to `.push()`, tried to do `message+="message"` tried to `concat();` None seems to work.

Edit

I set the variable name to whatever i wish it to be, but the msg_data.message is how the message appears, and i dont even put it in a loop. It uses a queryselector.

The code that i wrote to get the message through the Strophe plugin:

```
conn2.mam.query(jid, {
  "with": jid3,"before": '',"max":"10",
  onMessage: function(message) {


            var id = message.querySelector('result').getAttribute('id');
            var fwd = message.querySelector('forwarded');

            var d = fwd.querySelector('delay').getAttribute('stamp');
            var msg = fwd.querySelector('message');
            var msg_data = {

                id:id,
                with: Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(msg.getAttribute('to')),
                timestamp: (new Date(d)),
                timestamp_orig: d,
                from: Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(msg.getAttribute('from')),
                to: Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(msg.getAttribute('to')),
                type: msg.getAttribute('type'),
                body: msg.getAttribute('body'),
                message: Strophe.getText(msg.getElementsByTagName('body')[0])

                };
var message = msg_data.message;
console.log(message);
```

Strophe Mam Plugin

```
(function(){
'use strict';

Strophe.addConnectionPlugin('mam', {
    _c: null,
    _p: [ 'with', 'start', 'end' ],
    init: function (conn) {
        this._c = conn;
        Strophe.addNamespace('MAM', 'urn:xmpp:mam:0');
    },
    query: function (jid, options) {
        var _p = this._p;
        var attr = {
            type:'set',
            id:jid
        };
        var mamAttr = {xmlns: Strophe.NS.MAM};
        if (!!options['queryid']) {
            mamAttr.queryid = options['queryid'];
            delete options['queryid'];
        }
        var iq = $iq(attr).c('query', mamAttr).c('x',{xmlns:'jabber:x:data', type:'submit'});

        iq.c('field',{var:'FORM_TYPE', type:'hidden'}).c('value').t('urn:xmpp:mam:0').up().up();
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this._p.length; i++) {
            var pn = _p[i];
            var p = options[pn];
            delete options[pn];
            if (!!p) {
                iq.c('field',{var:pn}).c('value').t(p).up().up();
            }
        }
        iq.up();

        var onMessage = options['onMessage'];
        delete options['onMessage'];
        var onComplete = options['onComplete'];
        delete options['onComplete'];
        iq.cnode(new Strophe.RSM(options).toXML());

        this._c.addHandler(onMessage, Strophe.NS.MAM, 'message', null);
        return this._c.sendIQ(iq, onComplete);
    }
});

})();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with strophe but how does it return a `var message = ''`? If it returns a `var` (god knows how) it will always rewrite your preset var... If it could return it without the `var` then you might even be able to create a getter and setter method for this but otherwise its strange. What isn't clear from the question is how its 'returning'. Is it an ajax call? Is it executing a script with the `var message` set? So many unknowns...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, i added the strophe plugin i am using in the edit above, its not that long, but i really have no idea where it is setting the message either, all i do is call msg_data.message, no even with a loop, then all the messages appears.

Comment: Could you add the code you use to call this plugin as well? Then I can see what `this._c` is set to and understand what exactly is happening. If it is an event being fired with the data as the message then it could be easy to solve (set a global value and add the message, for example)

Comment: yes sorry just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you added would be non functional (its missing some closing brackets) but in essense I think you can do the following: at the top of your file add a global variable that you can concatenate:

```
var MESSAGE_FULL_STRING = '';
```

Now where you have the code `var message = msg_data.message;`, replace it with this:

```
MESSAGE_FULL_STRING += msg_data.message;
```

Now the full string should be stored in the variable `MESSAGE_FULL_STRING`, so just place a console log after that line (`console.log(MESSAGE_FULL_STRING)`) and the message should appear in your console extended every time the function is ran.

Comment: Hi, yer it is added them into the global variable, but just 1 quick problem, it is added them like a pyramid style, messages goes like this: Hi, HiHowareyou?, HiHowareyou?Iamfine...etc it seems like it is added in a looped fashion, but if i console log the MESSAGE_FULL_STRING outside, it is empty. Seems like the console.log thats outside the function got called first. So it was empty.

Comment: The only way to work with your full message after creating it is to call a function to do something with it _after_ it (calling the `console.log` outside of it will run it before anything has been set to the variable). The looped style probably has to do with how the plugin works (its returning the same value multiple times) and you could potentially work around that by saving the last result in another global variable and checking that the current result is not the same as the one your previously saved.

Comment: But i wont be able to save a last result in another global variable then compare to last one right? Because if the loop stops on, e.g. 10th message, the 10th is always different to 9th even when i += together.

Comment: No, thats not true. Instead of doing `+=`
, just assign it. Create a global called, say, `GLOBAL_COMPARE` and now change your assignment to `if(GLOBAL_COMPARE != msg_data.message){ MESSAGE_FULL_STRING += msg_data.message; GLOBAL_COMPARE = msg_data.message; } ` This will prevent any duplicates from showing up (at least if the duplicates come right _after_ each other. It will check if it's the same as the previous string and if its not add it and reassign the string to compare the next one too.

Comment: Hii, sorry, my brain was being slow, i literally just got it resolved, with a little different solution, i use the first half of your solution which was +=msg_data.message to add to the string, and then i use sessionstorage to setItem, it will automatically store just the latest, then no matter how long the loop is, it will always just save the last one, and i can just call it out whenever i need. Thanks so much for your help! And thanks so much for being patient with me!

Comment: Nice to hear you were able to solve it :) if my answers correct, could you mark it as such? Good luck with all your future excursions into javascript!

Comment: Thanks, yup just accepted it, also gave you a votes up as well haha